# How to use sockets to send user and password to a devboard, using SSH?

Tags: python-3.x, sockets, google-coral

I am using sockets to connect to Coral devboard. I want to connect to the devboard and execute a classification script.
Whenever I execute my code (lines below) , it shows "In [3]:" for around 10 seconds as if waiting for something. Then "In [4]" appears. What is it happening? I already sent the user and password.

This is my code:

```
import socket

TCP_IP = '172.16.1.11'
TCP_PORT = 22
BUFFER_SIZE = 1024


s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((TCP_IP, TCP_PORT))

s.send(b'login')
print(s.recv(BUFFER_SIZE).decode())
s.send(b'mendel')
print(s.recv(BUFFER_SIZE).decode())

s.send(b'Password')
print(s.recv(BUFFER_SIZE).decode())
s.send(b'password')
print(s.recv(BUFFER_SIZE).decode())
```

THIS IS WHAT IS SHOWN IN THE CONSOLE

```
In [3]: runfile('C:/Users/Coral/Classification/demo_socket.py', wdir='C:/Users/Coral/Classification')
SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.9p1 Debian-10+deb10u2




In [4]:
```

EDIT

When I am using:

ssh mendel@172.16.1.11

I am already talking to the SSH server. Whay can't I just write the login and password using python instead of writing it with my fingers?

[image]

Comment: ahh, hard to tell, please give more info. This looks like you are just sending the data, but I'm very suspicious that it is being sent over port 22, that's ssh port. 
Do you have the code on the server side?

Comment: The code is in the devboard, isn't it? And when I connect by ssh, I am just sending ```ssh mendel@172.16.1.11``` It should work.

Comment: I'm sorry?
If you are expecting the server to do something, don't you need a client also?
Where is the client code?

Comment: The client code is the one I have written here.

Comment: when I connect using ssh to the devboard...I am communicating with the SSH server of the devboard. So why when "automating" with python code I cannot just connect?

Comment: hi again, what exactly is the end goal here? 
If this is the client code, then where is the server code? 
You'll definitely need a server setup on the dev board that does something like this:
1) Open a tcp connection on a specific port (your client need to connect to this port, not 22)
2) Wait for client connection
3) Connected to client
4) Wait for command to run from client
5) Run command

Right now you're just sending those bytes to the dev board over port 22, that's why you're not getting anything back :)

Comment: Thr goal is to use python to connect to the board and execute a script. I have tried using the serial port and now with sockets.

Comment: Check my other question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62419187/how-to-execute-commands-in-a-remote-server-using-python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it using "paramiko".

```
import paramiko

#Server's data
IP = '172.16.2.47'
PORT = 22
USER = 'mendel'
PASSWORD = 'mendel'

ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect(hostname = IP, port=PORT, username = USER, password = PASSWORD)


stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command('hostname -I')
output = stdout.readlines()
type(output)
print('\n'.join(output))
'''
```